# PHP serialize alternative with less storage needs

Tags: php, serialization

Is there a an alternative to PHP's serialize which needs less space?

I'm asking because I've serialized an array of objects and I've noticed that most of the bytes are used to save the name of the class. Consequently the same string appears again and again even if it is not necessary.

Comment: There's [igbinary](http://pecl.php.net/package/igbinary)

Comment: @MarkBaker I can't install extensions but it does what I want.

Comment: If you can't install external components, then you're basically limited to the built-in serialize... it works, even if it's a bit slow and doesn't shrink the data, but it wasn't designed to reduce datasize

Comment: @MarkBaker What about a library?

Answer (score 0):

implementing a serialization is the easy bit:

```
function serialize2($arr){
  result='';
  foreach($arr as $key=>$val) $result.=(is_array($val)?serialize2($val):$key.'=>'.$val)
  return result;
}
```

The tricky bit is the rule based compression. When you say "I've noticed that most of the bytes are used to save the name of the class" you basicly say "there seems to be a rule, how things can be out put in a more compressed way". As I do not know your data and you do not seem to have identified which rules there are, my help stops at this point. From here you can try to identify the rules and build them into the serialization function I gave you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but your function is not bijective. I've also mentioned that I want to serialize an array of objects which your function does not support.

Comment: Well, the inversion is a recursion of explodes. I gave you a pattern. You need to work in your detailed requirements yourself. The loop for object and unserialize support looks like this: foreach($arr as $key=>$val) $result.=((is_array($val) or is_object($val))?('{'.serialize2($val).'}'):$key.':'.$val).','; I think the essence of my answer is: The most efficient (and basically not that hard)way of serialization is to code it yourself based on your specific requirements.

Comment: I've already tried. It works but the performance is worse than of the standard serialize-function.